# removing object in an array based on one of it's properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to manipulate an array of components inside the state and I want to be able to remove each component based on it's `id` property. I cant figure out how to target the component when I pass the `id` dynamically each time I create the component.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
        counters: 0, // counters count    
        countersArr: []
    }}

render() {

        let countersArrCop = this.state.countersArr;
        let counterIndex;

    onAddCounterHandler = () => {

        const id = new Date().getTime()
        console.log(this.state.countersArr.length)
        console.log(counterIndex)
        countersArrCop.push( // push new counter to the counters holder
            <Counter 
                style={styles.countersContainer} 
                key={id}
                id={id}
                remove={() => removeCounterHandler(id)}
            />
        )

        this.setState({
            countersArr: countersArrCop,
        })
        console.log(id)
    }

    // remove counter
    removeCounterHandler = (id) => {
        console.log(id)
        const countersArr = this.state.countersArr.slice(); // Local copy to manipulate
        this.setState({ countersArr: countersArr.filter(counter => counter.id !== id) });
      }

        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>

                <View style={styles.addBtnContainer}>
                    <Button 
                        onPress={onAddCounterHandler} 
                        title={'add Counter'}
                    />
                </View>

                {
/* return each individual counter from the array by using 'map' */
}
                <View style={styles.container}> {
                    this.state.countersArr.map((counter) => {
                        return counter;
                    })
                }
                </View>

            </View>
        );
```

UPDATED THE CODE *** `id` === `undefined`.. why?

Comment: `this.state.countersArr = this.state.countersArr.filter(c => c.id !== id)`

Comment: you can't manipulate the state like this.

Comment: You are right sorry. But you get the idea. Use the filter function to get the new array then use `setState()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all putting logical codes in your `render()` is highly discouraged. render should only render, any other task should be where they should be. Note that all the code in your render block gets called **every time the component re-renders.** So those handlers should be declared as methods within your component class with proper hooks from your render like maybe `onClick()` and don't forget to bind your `this` context like this to keep your `this` reference to your component class inside your methods:

```js
<Button onClick={this.onAddCounterHandler.bind(this)} />
```

second, you're bloating your state with an array of components when you can just store the ids in an array:

```js
onAddCounterHandler() {
    const { countersArr } = this.state
    const id = new Date().getTime()
    this.setState({
        countersArr: [...countersArr, id],
    })
}
```

then just map that array and return the component like this:

```
{ this.state.countersArr.map(id=>
    <Counter 
        style={styles.countersContainer} 
        key={id}
        id={id}
        remove={this.removeCounterHandler.bind(this, id)}
    />
) }
```

note that in jsx, this statement should be enclosed in braces {}

then on your filtering function:

```js
removeCounterHandler(filteredID) {
    const { countersArr } = this.state
    const filtered = countersArr.filter(id=>id!==filteredID)
    this.setState({ countersArr: filtered});
  }
```

Lastly, NEVER ever put setState in your render

try it and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: man THANK YOU! I don't even know what I did but its work!!! if you dont mind to explain what is `const { countersArr } = this.state` and `countersArr: [...countersArr, id]` mean and how i dont had to set state at the top? (im very new to react as you can see) Thank you again!!

Comment: That my friend is called object destructuring and that one is called spread operator.

The idea is, you must finalize your data before calling `render()` to avoid calling `setSate()` inside your `render()`. That is a matter of anti pattern and MUST be avoided.

Comment: Ill read about it because I have no idea what `object destructuring ` means! thanks again I am struggle with it for two days now, each time I had other bug. your solution is perfect.!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a function like this one:

```
removeCounterHandler (id) {
  const countersArr = this.state.countersArr.slice(); // Local copy to manipulate
  this.setState({ countersArr: countersArr.filter(counter => counter.id !== id) });
}
```

Comment: ok I get the `id` and all but is still wont update the state and wont remove the element